# How to get the Label of a Formula field dynamically

Tags: apex, describesobject, dynamic

I'm trying to use Salesforce describe methods to get an object dynamically, and they get all the labels to that object.

I am trying to use the following code, but the map being returned doesn't include formula fields.  Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = gd.get( 'Custom_Object__c' ).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> myFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get( 'MyObject__c' ).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String apiName : myFields.keySet())
{
    Qutils.debug(apiName + '==>'+myFields.get(apiName).getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

Comment: how is this dynamic ?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: This works to get the Formula Fields when I know the Object ahead of time, but is there a way to get the Object dynamically also if I don't know it ahead of time?

Comment: it's almost the same. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to show the label via a visualforce page so you don't have static values per each API field, use the following example within the visualforce page to correctly display the label even if it changes on the administrative side:

```
{!$ObjectType.Campaign.fields.Name.label}
{!$ObjectType.Campaign.fields.CustomFieldAPIName__c.label}
```

Bonus:

```
printFields('Account');
public void printFields(String sObjectName){
    SObjectType sot = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName);
    Map<String,Schema.Sobjectfield> fieldInfo = sot.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(String s :fieldInfo.keySet()){
         system.debug('APIName: ' + s + '\nAPIFieldLabel: ' + fieldInfo.get(s).getDescribe().getLabel()); 
    }
}
```